# Compilation error in a Macro to drop an Alert based on 3 conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a macro based on the following formula

```
=IF(AND(A4<>"";TODAY()+7>=A4;C31="");"Yes";"")
```

So if the 3 conditions are true then the macro will drop an Alert message, there are 2 conditions on a range A4:A24 and one condition on another C31:C51. However, I managed to make it work just with the two first conditions with the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Dim DateDueCol As Range

Dim DateDue As Range

Dim NotificationMsg As String

Set DateDueCol = sheet2.Range("A4:A24") 'the range of cells that contain your due dates

For Each DateDue In DateDueCol

'Change H2 to the cell for bring forward reminder days in your data

If DateDue <> "" And Date >= DateDue - 7 Then

'Change the offset value to pick up the invoice number column in your data

NotificationMsg = NotificationMsg & " " & DateDue.Offset(0, 1)

End If

Next DateDue

If NotificationMsg = "" Then

MsgBox "You do not need to chase any invoices today."

Else: MsgBox "The followinging invoices need chasing today: " & NotificationMsg

End If

End Sub
```

That one worked well but when I tried to introduce the third condition I started to get one compilation mistake after the other, I tried to check it with AIs but once they fixed all the buggs, the macro didn't do a thing so probably my code isn't right at all. Anyway, heres my attemp to implement the third condition:

```
Option Explicit

Public MacroEjecutado As Boolean

Sub Workbook_Open()

MacroEjecutado = False

End Sub

Sub Worksheet_Activate()

If MacroEjecutado = False Then

MacroEjecutado = True

Dim DateDueCol As Range

Dim DateDue As Range

Dim StatusCol As Range

Dim Status As Range

Dim NotificationMsg As String

Set DateDueCol = sheet2.Range("A4:A24") 'the range of cells that contain your due dates

For Each DateDue In DateDueCol

Set StatusCol = sheet2.Range("C31:C51") 'the range of cells that contain your status

For Each Status In StatusCol

If DateDue <> "" And Date >= DateDue - 7 Then 'Change the offset value to pick up the invoice number column in your data

If Status.Row = DateDue.Row + 27 And IsEmpty(Status) Then

NotificationMsg = NotificationMsg & " " & DateDue.Offset(0, 1)

End If

Next Status

End If

Next DateDue

End If

End Sub
```

I got the "Next without For" error on this one.

Comment: Oftentimes proper indentation will help find the error.

Comment: `I got the "Next without For" error on this one.` Move the `End If` after the `Next Status` before it. So `End If` first and then `Next Status`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Sure, but after I do that it doesn't drops any alert, not even after reopenig the file

Comment: Yes that is a different issue. My comment was about the error message. Let me check out your code.

Comment: Ok. Quick question. Do you want to show an alert or fill a cell?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I want it to show an alert, the first code works but the last one with a third condition don't.

Comment: @SiddharthRout that's right, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generated the string message (NotificationMsg) but forgot to add the

"`MsgBox NotificationMsg`" line to trigger the message box.

I completed the missing part based on the last 5 lines of the first code and this is how it looks the corrected version:

```
Option Explicit

Public MacroEjecutado As Boolean

Sub Workbook_Open()

MacroEjecutado = False

End Sub

Sub Worksheet_Activate()

If MacroEjecutado = False Then

MacroEjecutado = True

Dim DateDueCol As Range

Dim DateDue As Range

Dim StatusCol As Range

Dim Status As Range

Dim NotificationMsg As String

Set DateDueCol = sheet2.Range("A4:A24") 'the range of cells that contain your due dates

For Each DateDue In DateDueCol

Set StatusCol = sheet2.Range("C31:C51") 'the range of cells that contain your status

For Each Status In StatusCol


If DateDue <> "" And Date >= DateDue - 7 Then 'Change the offset value to pick up the invoice number column in your data

If Status.Row = DateDue.Row + 27 And Status = "" Then

NotificationMsg = NotificationMsg & " ," & DateDue.Offset(0, 1)


End If
End If

Next Status
Next DateDue

If NotificationMsg = "" Then

MsgBox "You don't need to chase any invoice today."

Else: MsgBox "The following invoices need to be chased: " & NotificationMsg

End If
End If

End Sub
```

Siddarth's answer worked OK, but the message just gives me the number of the cells of another column -I needed the proyection of those cells in the column in front- while my code included the values of the cells of the correct column on the alert, but I hightly appreciate his time and efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this. Do let me know if you get an error. Also customize the alert as per your needs.

```
'“=IF(AND(A4<>"";TODAY()+7>=A4;C31="");"Yes";"")”

Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim msgAlert As String
    Dim dt As Date
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    With ws
        For i = 4 To 24
            '~~> Check if the cells in Col A and C are not empty
            If Len(Trim(.Range("A" & i).Value2)) <> 0 And _
                Len(Trim(.Range("C" & i + 27).Value2)) <> 0 Then
                
                '~~> Get the date from the "A" cell
                dt = .Range("A" & i).Value2
                
                '~~> 3rd Condition
                If DateDiff("d", dt, Date) >= 7 Then
                    If msgAlert = "" Then
                        msgAlert = "A" & i
                    Else
                        msgAlert = msgAlert & ", A" & i
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Invoices in cells " & msgAlert & " needs to be chased"
End Sub
```

Comment: It's giving me the opposite the ones not expired, I mean, the macro gave me the ones that the formula didn't mark as "yes".  The intention of the macro is to to alert before the Due date of some invoices 7 seven days before expiration and name the cells of the column of both, the expired and the ones about to expire in 7 days that hasn't been paid yet. This is the formula of the conditional format rule which highlights the cells of the invoices not paid expired and about to expire in 7 days "AND(B4<>"";TODAY()+7>=A4;C31="")"

The macro is supose to show the alert with the highlighted values

Comment: Simply change the condition here `If DateDiff("d", dt, Date) >= 7 Then`